# How to return list of strings if a string in a list contains another string python

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

If i have a list of strings, I want to return the strings in that list that are contained in the strings of that list. For instance: ["red", "blue", "loss", "boss", "sloss"] would return ["loss"]. I have been trying to do this only using lambdas + filter and no loops/comprehensions but can't seem to figure out why my solution isnt working:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x if x in stringlist else "", stringlist))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if the strings are in the lsit of string, not if the strings are substrings of one of the strings.

Try:

```
list(filter(lambda x: any(x in y and x != y for y in stringlist), stringlist))
```

It checks if the strings are stricly contained in one of the other string ( `x in y and x != y` )  so it will not match equal strings in the `list`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, is it possible to achieve this without the for looping?

Comment: I don't think so as you will have to go through every item of your list at least once. If this answers the question, can you mark the topic as closed ? Thanks !